# Could not find ParserDetails.ini

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

```
could not find ParserDetails.ini in /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/SAX
 at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/SAX.pm line 212
        XML::SAX::do_warn('XML::SAX', 'could not find ParserDetails.ini in /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/...') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/SAX.pm line 62
        XML::SAX::load_parsers('XML::SAX') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/SAX.pm line 115
        XML::SAX::parsers('XML::SAX') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/SAX/ParserFactory.pm line 18
        XML::SAX::ParserFactory::new('XML::SAX::ParserFactory') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/SAX/ParserFactory.pm line 26
        XML::SAX::ParserFactory::parser('XML::SAX::ParserFactory', 'Handler', 'XML::Simple=HASH(0x162c6e30)') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/Simple.pm line 358
        XML::Simple::build_tree('XML::Simple=HASH(0x162c6e30)', 'changelog.xml', 'undef') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/Simple.pm line 308
        XML::Simple::build_simple_tree('XML::Simple=HASH(0x162c6e30)', 'changelog.xml', 'undef') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/Simple.pm line 227
        XML::Simple::parse_file('XML::Simple=HASH(0x162c6e30)', 'changelog.xml') called at /reports/ie/lib/cpan/XML/Simple.pm line 195
        XML::Simple::XMLin('XML::Simple=HASH(0x162c6e30)', 'changelog.xml') called at perlXML_test.pl line 11
```

Comment: You dump some error message and expect help?

Answer (score 7):

It's a warning saying you don't have any SAX parser for XML::SAX to use except the slow and buggy XML::SAX::PurePerl.

Installing a parser for XML::SAX will update the file, creating it if necessary.

```
cpan XML::LibXML::SAX
```

You could also tell XML::Simple to use XML::Parser instead of XML::SAX.

```
$XML::Simple::PREFERRED_PARSER = 'XML::Parser';
```

Setting environment variable `XML_SIMPLE_PREFERRED_PARSER` to the same value will have the same effect.

XML::Parser is much faster backend than any of the XML::SAX parsers that exited when I did benchmarks a couple of years ago. It doesn't handle namespaces, though.

Personally, I'd avoid XML::Simple. It's the hardest XML parser to use correctly. I use XML::LibXML.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try to work on it with XML::LibXML. Is this library from CPAN?

Comment: Yes, it's there, though it requires the libxml2 C++ library. If your OS distro provides that, you should go with that. On Windows and ActivePerl, you can use `ppm install XML::LibXML`

Comment: This bash one-liner worked for me: `sax=\`perl -MXML::SAX -le 'print $INC{"XML/SAX.pm"}'\`; sax="${sax%%.pm}/ParserDetails.ini"; [ -e "$sax" ] || printf "[XML::SAX::PurePerl]\nhttp://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces = 1\n" | sudo tee "$sax"`